# why is typescript overriding property decorator with undefined value

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I am trying out decorators and wanted to create a library. But I got stuck with an unexpected behavior.

Why is this property decorator overridden by the construction? What is happening behind the scene that make the property definition change from a getter/setter to value type property.

This is really confusing, since as I know during the construction it was not even supposed to create the field with undefined value, since the only value given to this field is 1 from the decorator, and it is a getter.

PS: I have tried typescript 4.9.5 and 5.1.6 same result.

```
function description(target, key, title?: string) {
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
  console.log(title ?? 'description', desc);
  return desc;
}

function FakeFactory<T = any>() {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: any) {
    let _value: any = 1;

    description(target, propertyKey, 'before');
    // console.log: before undefined

    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey as string, {
      get() {
        return _value;
      },
      set(newValue: T) {
        _value = newValue;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });

    description(target, propertyKey, 'after');
    // console.log: after 
    // { get: [λ: get], 
    //   set: [λ: set], 
    //   enumerable: true, 
    //   configurable: true }
  };
}

function Deco() {
  return FakeFactory();
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    description(this, 'field', 'constructor');
    // console.log: constructor
    // { value: undefined, 
    //   writable: true, 
    //   enumerable: true, 
    //   configurable: true } 
  }

  @Deco()
  field: string;
}
const a = new A();
description(a, 'field', 'final');
// console.log: final
// { value: undefined, 
//   writable: true, 
//   enumerable: true, 
//   configurable: true }

// Expected field definition  
// { get: [λ: get], 
//   set: [λ: set], 
//   enumerable: true, 
//   configurable: true }
```

tsconfig of this code

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "incremental": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn;t you return descriptor from decorator?

Comment: @Dimava you cant return descriptor form **property decorator** check the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "target" parameter of before description(**target**.., "before") it's the A class constructor itself and the "target"  parameter of after  description(**target**.., "after") is an object because **defineProperty** add or modify property and return **object**

Check demo (Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators.) :

```
import "reflect-metadata";

function description(target: any, key: any, title?: string) {

  const desc = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
  console.log(title ?? 'description', desc);
  return desc;

}

function format(formatString: string) {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {

    description(new target.constructor(), propertyKey, 'before');

    Reflect.defineProperty(target.constructor.prototype, propertyKey, {
      get() {
        return formatString?.replace("%s", this._value);
      },
      set(newValue: any) {
        this._value = newValue;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    })

    description(target, propertyKey, 'after');

  }
}

function Deco(formatString: string) {
  return format(formatString);
}

class Greeter {
  @Deco("Hello, %s")
  greeting: string = "demo";
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
}

const greeter = new Greeter('world');

console.log(greeter.greeting);
```

result :

```
[LOG]: "before",  {
  "value": undefined,
  "writable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
} 
[LOG]: "after",  {
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
} 
[LOG]: "Hello, world"
```

You can't return descriptor form property decorator because the property definitions doesn't change when calling description function but the code still working (not recommended):

```
// i declare custom Property Descriptor type equal to any
type TPropertyDescriptor = any

function description(target: any, key: any, title?: string) {

  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(new target.constructor(), key);
  console.log(title ?? 'description', desc);
  return desc;

}

function format(formatString: string) {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {

    description(target, propertyKey, 'before');

    let _value: string = '';

    const getter = function () {
      return formatString?.replace("%s", _value);;
    };

    // Set the modifiedMessage value
    const setter = function (newValue: string) {
      _value = newValue
    };


    const descriptor: TPropertyDescriptor = {
      set: setter,
      get: getter,
      configurable: true
    }


    description(target, propertyKey, 'after');

    // return descriptor
    return descriptor;
  }
}

function Deco(formatString: string) {
  return format(formatString);
}

class Greeter {
  @Deco("Hello, %s")
  greeting?: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
}

const greeter = new Greeter("world");

console.log(greeter.greeting);
```

output :

```
[LOG]: "before",  {
  "value": undefined,
  "writable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
} 
[LOG]: "after",  {
  "value": undefined,
  "writable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
} 
[LOG]: "Hello, world"
```

Comment: Thanks @Christa, I get it better, in fact I was trying to debug why the accessors were not applied and ended up with a code running properly for targets under es2021 only, and also I was debugging wrongly since I was not targeting the constructor as you corrected me.